# Crashing Retrofit + RxJava + SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, retrofit2, rx-java, x509certificate

I have implemented retrofit call with self-signed certificate. But, its get crashing everytime.
Although, its working in Postman and normal http client API calling.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**method for creating certificate**

```
 public static ArrayList<Object> buildSslSocketFactory() {
    ArrayList<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context mContext =MyApplication.getApplicationInstance();
    
    try {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream is = mContext.getResources().getAssets().open("certificate_name.crt");
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        objList.add(context.getSocketFactory());
        objList.add(tmf);
        return objList;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OnErrorNotImplementedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**method for retrofit client**

```
static OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient() {
    if (okHttpClient == null) {
        okHttpClient =
                new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(30,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = buildSslSocketFactory();
        SSLSocketFactory sslfac = (SSLSocketFactory) objectArrayList.get(0);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = (TrustManagerFactory) objectArrayList.get(1);

        okHttpClient.sslSocketFactory(sslfac, (X509TrustManager) (tmf.getTrustManagers()[0]));
    }
    return okHttpClient.build();
}
```

**Metho calling in Retrofit**

```
Retrofit retrofit =
                new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(provideGson())).addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).baseUrl(baseUrl).client(provideOkhttpClient()).build();
```

**Error Log**

```
 E: Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W: Unable to resolve superclass of Lano; (9320)
W: Link of class 'Lano;' failed
E: Could not find class 'ano', referenced from method amw.a
W: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 10218 (Lano;) in Lamw;
D: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
W: Unable to resolve superclass of Lano; (9320)
W: Link of class 'Lano;' failed
D: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xa2ef at 0x0a in Lamw;.a
W:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:381)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
W:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
W:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
W:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:42)
W:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
W:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
W:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
W:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
W:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
W:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
W:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
W:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:197)
W:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:584)
W:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W:     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
W:  ... 37 more
W: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W:  ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private TrustManager[] getWrappedTrustManagers(TrustManager[] trustManagers) {
        final X509TrustManager originalTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        return new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return originalTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        try {
                            originalTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certs, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                        try {
                            originalTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certs, authType);
                        } catch (CertificateException ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                }
        };
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
            throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
                    NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.your_cert); // your certificate file
        Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        caInput.close();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] wrappedTrustManagers = getWrappedTrustManagers(tmf.getTrustManagers());
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, wrappedTrustManagers, null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

And then set

```
okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Thanks! but its not working. okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory is deprecated.